# self.navigationController.topViewController as HomeViewController

Tags: xcode, swift, casting, navigationcontroller

I have a problem with the convert objective-c to swift.

For my train, i converted [MMPaper](https://github.com/mukyasa/MMPaper) to swift, but in the property :

**objective-c**

```
- (void)interactionBeganAtPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    // Very basic communication between the transition controller and the top view controller
    // It would be easy to add more control, support pop, push or no-op
    HASmallCollectionViewController *presentingVC = (HASmallCollectionViewController *)[self.navigationController topViewController];

    HASmallCollectionViewController *presentedVC = (HASmallCollectionViewController *)[presentingVC nextViewControllerAtPoint:point];
    if (presentedVC!=nil)
    {
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:presentedVC animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

**Swift**

```
func interactionBeganAtPoint(point: CGPoint) {
        var presentingVC: HomeViewController! = (self.navigationController.topViewController as HomeViewController)
        var presentedVC: HomeViewController! = (presentingVC.nextViewControllerAtPoint(point) as HomeViewController)

        if (presentedVC != nil) {
            self.navigationController.pushViewController(presentedVC!, animated: true)
        } else {
            self.navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        }
    }
```

The result is (problem in bold) :

```
libswiftCore.dylib`swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional:
...
0x10cf7da1e:  leaq   0x36b3d(%rip), %rax       ; "Swift dynamic cast failed"
0x10cf7da25:  movq   %rax, 0xb4a2c(%rip)       ; gCRAnnotations + 8
0x10cf7da2c:  int3   
**0x10cf7da2d:  movq   %rdi, %rax**
.....
```

You have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the `as` operator, you're telling Swift that you're absolutely sure that your downcasting to `HomeViewController` will succeed. However, clearly `presentingVC.nextViewControllerAtPoint(point)` can return `nil`, and you can't successfully downcast `nil` to `HomeViewController`.

When downcasting may fail, use the `as?` operator to return an optional value of the type you're trying to downcast to.

The following should work:

```
func interactionBeganAtPoint(point: CGPoint) {
    let presentingVC = self.navigationController.topViewController as? HomeViewController

    if let presentedVC = presentingVC?.nextViewControllerAtPoint(point) as? HomeViewController {
        self.navigationController.pushViewController(presentedVC, animated: true)
    } else {
        self.navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
}
```

(I've also made use of type inference to make the code more concise; when Swift sees `as? HomeViewController`, it figures out that the type of `presentingVC` must be `HomeViewController?`. Sorry if that was obvious.)

Comment: I tried        

var presentingVC: HomeViewController!
presentingVC = self.navController.topViewController as HomeViewController
println("presentingVC = \(presentingVC)")
var presentedVC: HomeViewController!
presentedVC = presentingVC?.nextViewControllerAtPoint(point) as? HomeViewController
println("presentedVC = \(presentedVC)")

result : 
presentingVC = <PaperSwift.HomeViewController: 0x7fd9e380b7d0>
presentedVC = nil

I don't understant, why presentedVC is nil !